# Blending DEM hillshade with QMS basemaps

Tags: qgis, dem, rendering, basemap

I would to keep the features of the ESRI Gray (Light) basemap crisp and clear on top of a hillshaded DEM in QGIS.  So far, my attempts have not been very successful.

The ESRI Gray basemap shows main roads in white, and darkened built-up areas on a light gray background.  This is the aesthetic I would like to preserve:

[image: I would like to preserve these features]

However, overlaying the basemap by blending with "MULTIPLY" on top of a hillshaded DEM tif with a z-factor of 0.00001000 (so as to not create too much darkness and contrast in the hillshade) still *really* obscures the basemap on top:

[image]

I tried making the DEM more transparent, but that fades the landscape features too much, which I would also like to preserve.

Is there a way to get rid of the "greyness" of the DEM that overshadows the features of the basemap, or somehow to keep the sharp features of the basemap to contrast with the DEM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Multiply blend mode can only darken a layer, not brighten it, so you could only use it for adding shadows from a hillshade layer to a base map, but not the highlights.

I would use the "Overlay" blend mode for this, rather than "Multiply". With Overlay, areas where the top layer is brighter than the bottom layer are brightened, and areas where the top layer is darker are darkened. Areas where the top layer is mid-grey remain unchanged. This makes it well suited for adding the shadows and highlights from the hillshade layer to the base map without altering the base map's overall brightness.

You need to adjust the brightness and contrast of the hillshade layer so the flat areas are 50 % grey, which looks unusually dark in Normal blend mode. In this example, I've set the layer brightness to -142, and the layer contrast to +33:

[image: hillshade]

Base map:
[image: basemap]

Overlay:
[image: Overlay]